# How to retrieve html from an xml?

Tags: python, html, xml, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I'm trying to get get HTML-Code from inside an XML File and all i get are the single elements.

XML-Example:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
  <websites>
    <website name="1">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
          <title/>
        </head><body>Sample Content.....</body>
      </html>
    </website>
  </websites>
```

I need a string containing only the html like this

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title/>
   </head><body>Sample Content.....</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you encountering a problem? Please provide the code you're working with, regardless if it works or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

example = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<websites>
  <website name="1">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
        <title/>
      </head><body>Sample Content.....</body>
    </html>
  </website>
</websites>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(example)
html = soup.find('html')
print(html)
```

Output:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
</head><body>Sample Content.....</body>
</html>
```